# Setup ssh for remote via (sub)domain

Tags: ssh, dns, scp, domain

Let's say I have a subdomain `test.example.com` at the IP `xyz.abc.xyz.abc`, which is the public address of my remote computer `A` with the user `testuser` and local address `xy.xy.ab.ab`. There are also more computers in the same network (with different local IP's of course).

What do I need to setup at the remote computer `A` and my home computer `B` to be able to execute commands like `ssh user@test.example.com` and `scp test.txt user@test.example.com:/home/user/` on `B` to reach `A`?

If it's important, I have the subdomain from `freedns.afraid.org`.

Comment: Does `A` really have a public address? Or is it behind a router?

Comment: You don't really need to do anything special, if the scenario is as described. Just create a DNS A record pointing test.example.com to xyz.abc.xyz.abc.

Comment: Hiding behind a router...